# Bus error in ARMv7 assembly function to find maximum element of array

Tags: c, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, armv7

I'm having trouble with an ARMv7 assembly function I'm trying to write. The function is below.

```
.global maxF32    

// float maxF32(const float x[], uint32_t count)
// returns the maximum value in the array (x) containing count entries
/* R0 = float x[], R1 = uint32_t count */
maxF32:
    CMP R1, #0         @ SET FLAGS OF COUNT
    BEQ maxF32_end     @ IF COUNT == 0, GO TO END
    MOV R2, R0         @ COPY R0 INTO R2
    MOV R0, #0         @ ZERO OUT R0
    MOV R3, #0         @ ZERO OUT R3
    MOV S0, R0         @ ZERO OUT S0
    MOV S1, R0         @ ZERO OUT S1
    MOV S2, R0         @ ZERO OUT S2
    B maxF32_loop      @ BRANCH TO LOOP
maxF32_loop:
    CMP R1, #0         @ CHECK IF COUNT == 0
    BEQ maxF32_end     @ IF SO, GO TO END
    VLDR.F32 S0, [R2]  @ LOAD CURRENT ELEMENT INTO S0
    ADD R2, R2, #4     @ INCREMENT VECTOR POINTER
    VLDR.F32 S1, [R2]  @ LOAD NEXT ELEMENT INTO S1
    SUB R1, R1, #1     @ DECREMENT COUNT
    CMP S0, S1         @ SET FLAGS; CHECK S0 - S1
    BMI maxF32_update  @ IF RESULT IS NEGATIVE (S1 > S0), GO TO UPDATE GREATEST
    B maxF32_loop      @ REPEAT LOOP
maxF32_update:
    VMOV R3, R1, S1  @ MOVE GREATER INTO GREATEST REGISTER
    B maxF32_loop    @ GO BACK TO LOOP
maxF32_end:
    MOV R0, R3  @ COPY GREATEST INTO R0
    BX LR       @ RETURN
```

I test with the following C code:

```
extern float maxF32(const float x[], uint32_t count);

#define COUNT 3

float x[] = {1.2, 1.3, 1.4};
float result;

result = maxF32(x, COUNT);

printf("result is %lf\n", result);
```

Using gdb, right around the second to last or last loop through the array, I get a "bus error" right around the `CMP S0, S1` line. I sometimes also get an "expected comma" at `MOV R3, R1, S1`, which confuses me as I don't know where I would need an extra comma.

Last note, I am coding on a Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

On a count of "3" you compare s0 to s1 3 times.... meaning you look for four elements in the array. (With `n` elements you really should only have `n-1` comparisons)

The logic...

```
decrement count
cmp element0 element1 ... loop
decrement count
compare element1 element2 ... loop
decrement count 
compare element2 with 'bus error' -- nothing there.
```

Moving `SUB R1, R1, #1` to the first line after `maxF32_loop:` probably fixes it as it puts the decrement before the check for count being 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that fixed the issue. Any ideas on that VMOV R3, R1, S1 line giving the error "expected comma"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it is doing that.  Good luck!